# MVC 5 Ninject - No parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I'm using MVC 5.2.3 and I have included packages

- Ninject
- Ninject.MVC5 (tried with MVC3 also)
- Ninject.Web.Common
- Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost

In NinjectWebCommon class (one that gets auto generated) I added
`kernel.Bind<ITestRepository>().To<TestRepository>().InRequestScope()` in `RegisterServices` method. I then have

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
    {
        protected readonly ITestRepository _testRepository;

        public ControllerBase(ITestRepository testRepository)
        {
            _testRepository = testRepository;
        }
    }
```

and

```
     public class HomeController : ControllerBase
     {
... some methods
     }
```

When I try to build solution I get

```
ControllerBase does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

Even when I add parameterless constructor it just triggers that one and interface doesn't get injected.

This should work out of the box, any idea why it isn't?

Comment: Does `HomeController` has any constructors defined?

Comment: @haim770 No constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `BaseController` doesn't have a parameter-less constructor, and its only constructor requires a `ITestRepository` argument, derived types are required to supply this argument by calling the base constructor.

Try this:

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public HomeController(ITestRepository testRepository) : base(testRepository)
    {

    }
}
```

This way, Ninject is able to inject `ITestRepository` implementation into the constructor of `HomeController` (the derived type) which in turn calls the base constructor (using `base()`) passing the required dependency.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645603(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: But this way i would need to define this for every controller. Is there a way to inject all interfaces in base and Just use them in derived controllers

Comment: I don't think there's a way around it. If your derived controller doesn't contain the necessary constructor to explicitly tell what the dependencies are, Ninject would simply not inject it. You may opt for property injection though, but that's less than optimal.

Comment: I'll just manually call ninject for each repository in new constructor. Thanks for help.